How to animate dimensions of Android compose Box based on user sliding a androidx.compose.material.Slider
My current android compose application allows the user to customise the apps icon dimension.
The user can slide a Slider between 0.5F to 2.0F to scale the icons, e.g. from half to double the size.
to support this use case i have a compose slider as shown here
var iconSizeAdjust by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(scaleFactor) }

val dynamicIconSize = remember(hotspotSizeAdjust) { (24 * (hotspotSizeAdjust)) }

Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.75f))

    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 10.dp)
            .weight(1f),
        value = scaleFactor,
        maxValue = 2.0F,
        minValue = 0.5F,
        steps = 15,
        onValueChanged = { customScale: Float ->
            onValueChanged(customScale)
            iconSizeAdjust = customScale
        }
    )
  

my slider is working fine, my issue is that i provide feedback to the user by showing an example custom sized icon in a rounded rectangle and some trailing text.
this is what i currently have in compose to display my example icon
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(0.5F),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
            .size(dynamicIconSize.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f))
        AsyncImage(
            model = iconUrl,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f))
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.6f).padding(end = 1.dp),
            text = "0",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 12.sp
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.1f))
    }
}

My issues are that at double the size the example has far to much padding at top and bottom, at half the size the only asset visible is part of the icon as shown in the following images
2 x Image

0.5 x Image

is it possible to achieve the desired effect and show a "useful" example to my users?
Where am i going wrong?
